# C++ compiling error

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a compiling error in C++  using classes. I have worked with classes before and have never encountered this error. I have tried adding static before the method `ImprtData` but that only prompted more errors.

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function bank.ImprtData;
```

here is my .cpp

```
#include "componets.h"

User::User() {
std::cout << "loaded" << std::endl;
}

void User::ImprtData() {

    std::cout << "loaded.\n";
}
```

and here is my .h

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class User {
    public:
            User();
            void write();
            void launch_main_menu();
            void login();
          void ImprtData();  
    private:
            void deposit();
            void withdrawl();
            std::string account_name;
            int account_pin;
            float account_balance;
            std::string account_user_name;
};
```

and finally my main

```
#include "componets.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Welcome to Bank 111.\n";
    User bank;
   bank.ImprtData;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it "componets.h" correct? Maybe `components.h`. 
Please add the file name on your example. I.e. you can write "and here is my `componets.h`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a simple typo. Replace

```
bank.ImprtData;
```

with

```
bank.ImprtData();
```

to *call* the function. The expression `bank.ImprtData` is confusing the compiler since it's interpreting it as the address of a function, and issues a diagnostic since the function is not `static`.

Comment: Mark to close if it is a simple typo, and add a comment.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: No, answers should be written in the answers section. And if the question is sufficiently well-written - as this one is aside from the insipid title - you can answer with reference to the compiler diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

`bank.ImprtData;` should be `bank.ImprtData();`